# Is it possible to have channel specific Rating fields?

Tags: solspace-rating

I am looking into using Solspace Rating for a web project I am working on and I will need to have different Rating fields for different channels. Is this possible? Or do I need to work out a way of hiding some fields for some channels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could display or not display the fields using a conditional based on the channel_id.

Comment: So to clarify, there is no way of setting channel-specific ratings fields and I need to hide them on the front end using conditionals. But that does mean that all fields are visible in the back-end, even if some are not relevant for some entries? This essentially means that I can't make any of the fields required unless they need to appear for all channels. Am I right?

Comment: Indeed all fields will be visible to all entries in the back-end. On the front-end however, you may be able to selectively change the contents of the `required=""` parameter based on channel_id and using conditionals (or embed variables), but you'll have to review the template parse order if you run into issues.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the same fields for each channel, but simply change the labels on the front end. We had a similar situation where each channel needed different fields but they all had the same number of fields. So we created 4 generic rating fields and then used a combination of channel short names and matching global variables to show the correct field labels for each channel.